# How to add service reference in visual studio with nettcpbinding hosted in IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, nettcpbinding

[image]

I have configured wcf service in IIS.
my web.config is

```
<services>
<service name="DNExpWCFService.Service1"        
behaviorConfiguration="DNExpWCFServiceBehaviour">
<endpoint name="WSGetEmployee" address="/WSGetEmployee"                       
binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="DNExpWCFService.IService1">
</endpoint>
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"
contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
</service>
</services>
```

Now when I add service reference using http://localhost:8333/Service1.svc it works fine. But for nettcpbinding I can't add service reference. I tried using net.tcp://localhost:8444/Service1.svc. But it also fails. How to add service reference using nettcpbinding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add service reference mex (IMetadataExchange) endpoint is used.
Try to add mex endpoint with **binding="mexTcpBinding"**

Comment: really helped. and one more doubt.why we are adding this line.What is the purpose of it?. <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding"
contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>

Comment: Same as for an endpoint with mexHttpBinding configuration: add special endpoint which will provide methods to return service description (aka wsdl), which is used for generating proxy classes for your service. So adding reference is in fact a generating of those proxy classes and appropriate client to access your service. After changing transport to TCP your service still remains being SOAP service.